# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am working on iBeacon technology and SIGTRAP occurred at **"[CoreLocationHandler locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:]"** delegate method. 
Inside this delegate method I am running a task over **DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, and using @autoreleasepool block** to save data locally.
This queue is returned by a static method of a singleton class, so I am not releasing this queue anywhere since various classes are using it. But still I am **receiving SIGTRAP crash**. Following is the important info regarding crash report.

`CRASH REPORT

Date/Time:           2015-11-18 06:34:02.920 +0000
Launch Time:         2015-11-18 06:28:56.798 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:<br/>

0   libdispatch.dylib               0x3276f6ac _os_object_retain + 32
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32229474 objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue + 4
2   MyApp                           0x000cf020 -[BusinessLayer initWithBeaconArray:withLocationManager:withDelegate:] (BusinessLayer.m:81)
3   MyApp                           0x000e51fe -[CoreLocationHandler locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:] (CoreLocationHandler.m:319)
4   CoreLocation                    0x2522049e 0x25212000 + 58526
5   CoreLocation                    0x2521ad06 0x25212000 + 36102
6   CoreLocation                    0x25214af4 0x25212000 + 10996
7   CoreFoundation                  0x24b275b2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 10
8   CoreFoundation                  0x24b26874 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
9   CoreFoundation                  0x24b253ae __CFRunLoopRun + 1710
10  CoreFoundation                  0x24a7361c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
11  CoreFoundation                  0x24a7342e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
12  GraphicsServices                0x2be220a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
13  UIKit                           0x2805e354 UIApplicationMain + 1436
14  MyApp                           0x000e815c main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3278eaac start + 0`

Comment: Please post the body of `BusinessLayer initWithBeaconArray:withLocationManager:withDelegate:`.

Comment: Please also show the full code inside the async task.

Comment: @davidgyoung I can't post the full code here, but I am sending you over your email.

Comment: @JAL: I can post this on your email only, please share your email id

Comment: Please post using a github gist (or other public forum) so others can see, too.